# .gif files not reflecting delay changes in xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, animation, gif

i am using .gif files in my xcode project. I have replaced my gif with different time delays between frames. But it does not reflect the changes. The changes between frames have been done in gif itself. the preview of that .gif file shows the changes but on the simulator it does not reflect the same delay! Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you with a simpler solution, you can inherit [this library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) and then you simply have to add a single method that is

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"JuU08" withExtension:@"gif"];
[SharedImageButton setImageWithURL:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] placeholderImage:[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]];
```

Where **JuU08** is the name of the gif image that you have added to your project. Here I have added the image to a `UIButton` in a `UITableView`.

Link :- https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Instead of adding multiple frames with time delays which can become tiring . Hope this helps ....

Comment: what is SharedImageButton and ImageArray?

Comment: sorry my bad! What should i do to display a gif image in UIImageView?

Comment: Simply add UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; instead of the second line....

Comment: then UIImageView *modalBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
modalBackground.image = imageOfGif;

Comment: Be aware that the uiimage-from-animated-gif project contains a flaw that can cause your app to crash if the animated GIF is too large because all app memory can be consumed by the GIF decoding. If you have really small GIFs with only a few frame that it might be okay.